# Determining why access denied

Tags: drupal-6

I'm tried to determine why some of my users are being denied editing rights (they get the access denied page)

Is there some simple way to get the name of the module doing the denying OR the reason access is being denied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, I rebuilt the nodes and that seemed to do the trick. First time I've had that actually work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue. Look to see what role is assigned to them, then see what permissions that role has at the page admin/user/permissions. Try checking "administer nodes". This should allow them to do anything with nodes (or alternatively check the "edit" permissions to for the content type needed). If that doesn't work, see if there is anything telling in the recent log entries at admin/reports/dblog. If you have any content access/ACL type modules installed, you may want to double check the settings for that.